# Is it possible to open Adobe Illustrator files from last close?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

Say you have three files open in Adobe Illustrator, but you exit out of the program. Is there a way that you can have those three files opened back up when you open up Illustrator again? Similar to how most text editor programs are set up -- so when you open up the program again all your last stayed-open files are there.

Also, does anyone know what the terminology for this saving-behavior is? State-saving? Googling to find the answer is difficult within the sea of Illustrator 'saving files' questions.

Answer (score 1):

No, Illustrator does not have built-in persistent files capability. [Here's a question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/21335/8708) on Graphic Design looking for the same feature. It does happens when the program crashes, then the [recovery dialog](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/how-to/recover-files.html) will open up anything that was auto-saved. But I wouldn't recommend purposefully crashing Illustrator just to accomplish this.

If you're interested in a slightly less automated solution, you might be able to write a script to save your current list of opened documents and re-load it later. [The API](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/illustrator/scripting.html) gives access to `Application.documents` and `Application.open()`. But that would still require some manual labor of running the script each time you need to save or re-load the document list.

> `Application.documents` - Read-only. The documents in the application.
>
> `Application.open(file [, documentColorSpace] [, options])` - Opens the specified document file.